# How to switch tabs in Edge on Mac using trackpad (touch pad)?

Tags: macos, microsoft-edge

I've very often use Edge on fullscreen (Virtual Desktop 2) and use trackpad (touchpad) on Mac a lot. It would be very convenient to switch between tabs by gesture.